# не работают параметры на red hat linux 8

Tags: linux

Установил red hat linux 8! И почему то не работает пункт Параметры. Окно открывается, но оно не отзывчивое! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обратитесь в техподдержку дистрибутива. Насколько я помню, RHEL 8 — это платный дистрибутив. Или вы о старом Red Hat 8?